# How to serialize a part of json

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization, json-simple

I have a json file with users, each users has `email` and `password` and corresponding POJO exist to deserialize them.

I'm using both `jackson` and `JSON.simple`.

However, I want to add users at will, and create a method to find them by their description, let's say this is my json:

```
{
  "user1": {
    "email": "user1@user.com",
    "password": "qwe123",
  },
  "user2": {
    "email": "user2@user.com",
    "password": "abc123",
  },

...
  "userX": {
    "email": "userX@user.com",
    "password": "omg123",
  }
}
```

This is my POJO:

```
public record User(String email, String password) {}
```

I dont want to create superPOJO and add each user as I create them.

I would like to create method that would read my json, and returned  the `User` object based on String input.

For now I created users in array and get them using their index, but now situation requires giving users "nicknames" and getting them by their nickname.

Now I am keeping user like this:

```
[
  {
    "email": "xxx@xxx.com",
    "password": "xxx111",
  },
  {
    "email": "yyy@yyy.com",
    "password": "yyy222",
  }
]
```

This is my current method:

```
public User getUser(int index) throws IOException {
    return Parser.deserializeJson(getUserFile(), User[].class)[index];
}
```

where `Parser#deserializeJson()` is:

```
public <T> T deserializeJson(String fileName, Class<T> clazz) throws IOException {
    return new ObjectMapper().readValue(Utils.reader(fileName), clazz);
}
```

And `Utils.reader` just brings file from the classpath.

I would like a method like this:

```
public User getUser(String nickname) throws IOException {
    return Parser.deserializeJson(getUserFile(), User.class);
}
```

and when calling this method with parameter `nickname` of `user2` I'd get `User` object with fields: email `user2@user.com` and password `abc123`

Comment: `Parser.deserializeJson` returns an array of type `User`. Simply search that array for the user with the nickname you are looking for

Comment: @AlgoRythm but new json is JSONObject not JSONArray :(

Comment: can do with jackson library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your input json is an object (map) of User-like objects:

```java
{
  "user1": {
    "email": "user1@user.com",
    "password": "qwe123",
  },
  "user2": {
    "email": "user2@user.com",
    "password": "abc123",
  },

...
  "userX": {
    "email": "userX@user.com",
    "password": "omg123",
  }
}
```

then you should be able to deserialize it into a (Hash)Map of Users:

```java
public <T> Map<String, Class<T>> deserializeJson(String fileName) throws IOException {
    return new ObjectMapper().readValue(Utils.reader(fileName), new TypeReference<HashMap<String, Class<T>>>(){});
}
```

and then use it like so:

```java
public User getPredefinedUser(String nickname) throws IOException {
    return Parser.deserializeJson(getUserFile(), User.class).get(nickname);
}
```

(Although you probably want to parse once and store that somewhere, not parse every time).

*Thanks for the compile check and fix by hetacz. Had the templates wrong, and an unnecessary (for this case) class variable*

Comment: Your deserializeJson doesnt compile, I wrote sth like this:

    public <T> Map<String, Class<T>> toMap(String fileName) throws IOException {
        return MAPPER.readValue(Utils.reader(fileName), new TypeReference<HashMap<String, Class<T>>>(){});
    }

Comment: Thanks! Fixed it. I imagine that the `clazz` variable is unnecessary because it can be inferred by the return type? Haven't done java in a while :)

Comment: I guess so, in my case I just completely changed it from public <T> Map<String, Class<T>>  to public Map<String, User>, as I found, that I don't have other cases in my code for now, but I guess if I wanted to keep it generic and tried to deserialize something deserializable to another existing object, it would have worked.

Answer (score 0):

After putting some thought into my own problem I decided to do it like this (I also dropped using a `JSON.simple` library in the meantime, as per suggestion that using two for such a simple task is an overkill).

I am using `com.fasterxml.jackson.core` - Jackson Databind.

I used helper function from `Parser` class where `MAPPER` is a `new ObjectMapper()`:

```
    public JsonNode toJsonNode(String fileName) throws IOException {
        return MAPPER.readTree(Utils.reader(fileName));
    }
```

here is also a `parseJson` method from `Parser` class:

```
    public <T> T parseJson(String json, Class<T> clazz) throws JsonProcessingException {
        return MAPPER.readValue(json, clazz);
    }
```

I wrapped it all together in method I wanted (that searches by nickname) and everything works fine, I get desired `User` object in the end:

```
    public User getUser(String nickname) throws IOException {
        return Parser.parseJson(Parser.toJsonNode(USERS).get(nickname).toString(), User.class);
    }
```

And now the test:

```
    @Test(groups = Group.TEST)
    public void jsonTest() throws IOException, ParseException {
        User user = Utils.getUser("user2");
        log.warn(user.email());
        log.warn(user.password());
    }
```

output is:

```
2022-11-23 T 02:47:58.177+0100 [28][WARN] tests.smoke.SmokeTest->jsonTest user2@user.com
2022-11-23 T 02:47:58.177+0100 [28][WARN] tests.smoke.SmokeTest->jsonTest abc123
```

On the side note I think I will switch to one JSON library in my whole projects, having two of them is unnecessairly causing mess.

Other thing I found important is, when getting to the value behind a key, use `asText()` method not `toString()`, as `toString()` returned text in double quotes! This is actual code fragment from my automation framework:

```
expected:<"["This field is required"]"> but was:<"[This field is required]">
```

So it basically put quotes over quotes, that every string in JSON has to be wrapped in anyway...

Comment: Seems like overkill, using two libraries to do what one could, but it does work...

Comment: Working with `JsonNode`s is awkward, use Jackson mapper to parse into a `Map` as described in @GarrettMotzner's answer.